# How is nodejs package installation root directory determined?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I have my nodejs package (suppose MY_PACKAGE) that is being installed from github. This packages depends on `sass-loader` package.

When server configuration is `v7.8.0 + yarn v0.24.5` after `yarn install` there is a `sass-loader` directory at the project root `node_modules` directory.

When server configuration is `v8.9.4 + yarn v1.3.2` after `yarn install` `sass-loader` package is installed in `node_modules/MY_PACKAGE/node_modules` directory.

Is there a way how I can control where the `sass-loader` package is being installed? I need it in the root `node_modules` because I cannot build my project otherwise.

And why is not `sass-loader` being installed in root directory like `file-loader` package. `npm ls ...` command shows that only MY_PACKAGE depends on both these packages.

Comment: just add sass-loader to your package.json then it will always be installed at the top level

Comment: I did it before asking) It really works. But it is interesting to clarify such behaviour.